# Safari iOs: Possible to create Youtube Playlist functionality?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, youtube, mobile-safari

**Situation:** See this site as example: http://www.projekktor.com/demo-d.php It works perfectly on all browsers. On iOs devices it shows the first video correctly.

**Problem**: "Next" button being showed in Youtube Player on iOs device doesn't work.

**What I tried:** Did a long search on google but couldn't find anything. Only solutions for Object-C iOs Apps.

**Question:** Is it possible to inject youtube playlists on iOs devices. Any undocumented API calls someone is aware of?